# Applying purrr::map over each of a vector of characters

Tags: r, list, dataframe, purrr

I'm working on trying to understand the purrr::map function a little better. Let's say I have a simple vector of characters, and I want to run some function that outputs a data frame using each character as an input.

Here's a toy example

```
animals <- c('sheep', 'cow', 'horse')

make_df <- function(x){
    data.frame(r1 = rnorm(1:5), r2 = rnorm(1:5), an = x)
}
```

Here's what `make_df`

```
> make_df('sheep')
r1          r2           an
-0.18069698 -0.4767575  sheep
0.09580225  0.2785548   sheep
-0.74701529 0.2673391   sheep
-1.62795239 1.0026010   sheep
0.36573951  -0.2323944  sheep
```

Now, I want to run this function for each animal and save each dataframe to a list, and put that list in a new data frame where one column is the animals and one column is the list of data frames (which I'll use with other tidyverse functions).

I think the way to do that would be something like
`data.frame(animals = animals) %>% mutate(ldf = map(animals, make_df(.)))`

```
 data.frame(animals = animals) %>% mutate(ldf = map(animals, make_df(.)))
```

but this gives me an error

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 3. Traceback:
>
> 1. data.frame(animals = animals) %>% mutate(ldf = map(animals, make_df(.)))
> 2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
> 3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
> 8. function_list[[k]](value)
> 9. mutate(., ldf = map(animals, make_df(.)))
> 10. mutate.data.frame(., ldf = map(animals, make_df(.)))
> 11. as.data.frame(mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...))
> 12. mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...)
> 13. mutate.tbl_df(tbl_df(.data), ...)
> 14. mutate_impl(.data, dots)
> ```

Of course, I can make this list of data frames with `lapply`

```
dfs <- lapply(animals, make_df)
```

But then if I try to bind dfs and animals into one data frame, I get a seemingly related error, again about differing numbers of rows.

```
 data.frame(animals, dfs)
```

> ```
> Error in data.frame(animals, dfs): arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 5 Traceback:
>
> 1. data.frame(animals, dfs)
> 2. stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s",   .     paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
> ```

Clearly, I am missing something fundamental here. Why am I unable to combine a list of characters and a list of data frames into one data frame manually, and how am I misusing `purrr::map` so that R runs into a problem, presumably trying to do the same within my functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is a little bit off, you'd either use `map(animals, make_df)` or `map(animals, ~ make_df(.))`, the second argument of `map` needs to be a function, which is the same as `lapply`:

```
data.frame(animals) %>% mutate(ldf = map(animals, make_df)) %>% as.tibble()
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  animals                  ldf
#   <fctr>               <list>
#1   sheep <data.frame [5 x 3]>
#2     cow <data.frame [5 x 3]>
#3   horse <data.frame [5 x 3]>

data.frame(animals) %>% mutate(ldf = map(animals, ~ make_df(.))) %>% as.tibble()
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  animals                  ldf
#   <fctr>               <list>
#1   sheep <data.frame [5 x 3]>
#2     cow <data.frame [5 x 3]>
#3   horse <data.frame [5 x 3]>
```

Or if using the `data.frame` constructor, you need to use `I` to create a list type column:

```
data.frame(animals, ldf = I(lapply(animals, make_df)))
#                         ^
```